# How can I set dynamic environment variables for Docker on Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku, environment-variables

I have a Ktor app deployed as a container on Heroku and want to [set database properties through environment variables as discussed here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url)
rather than putting the parsing logic in my app code since it seems very Heroku-specific. Since I deploy the app as a container the JDBC variables (`JDBC_DATABASE_URL`, `JDBC_DATABASE_USER` and `JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD`) are not defined for me.

Is it possible to parse `DATABASE_URL` to environment variables
in my `Dockerfile` or `heroku.yml`? A bash script for extracting them could look like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
regex="postgres://([^:]+):([^@]+)@(.+)"

if [[ $DATABASE_URL =~ $regex ]]
then
    export JDBC_DATABASE_USER="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    export JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    export JDBC_DATABASE_URL="jdbc:postgresql://${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
fi
```

but what do I have to do to make them available as environment variables in my app?

Comment: Yes possible. When you do `export` and then run your program from the `sh` script they'll be available as environment variable.